# Get all administrative users of our Facebook application

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We have multiple Facebook applications and each has multiple roles (administrators, developers, testers and analytics users).

We want to **export all the emails of the users with any of the above roles**, but we can't find a way to do it with the developer graph API.

Can we do it with only administrator access to the applications or do we must use the [Business Manager API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/get-started#update)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all users that have a role in the app via the `/{app-id}/roles` endpoint.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/app/roles

That will only give you their app-scoped user ids though.

Requesting their e-mail would have to happen separately, after you got the IDs - and will likely require that the user granted your app the email permission beforehand.